Handling the onDoubleClick Event in React and the library Three
I am working with a 3D model, and I want that when I double right-click on an object, the object gets centered on the screen. How can I do this? I have this code, but when I am far away from the object, it doesn't work, or it gives me coordinates that are not close to the object, or it places the camera in a position where the object is not visible. It is important to mention that the 3D object does not occupy the entire screen, as I have a left sidebar. I’m not sure if that affects it. The code I have is the following:
const onDoubleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    const headerHeight = document.querySelector('header')?.clientHeight || 0;
    const coords = new THREE.Vector2(
        (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
        -(((event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 - 1) - (headerHeight / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2) // Ajuste en Y
    );
  
    raycaster.setFromCamera(coords, camera);
  
    const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
    if (intersections.length > 0) {
        const selectedObject = intersections[0].object;
  
        const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(selectedObject);
        const size = boundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
        const center = boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
  
        const maxSize = Math.max(size.x, size.y, size.z);
        const baseDistance = maxSize * 2.5; 
  
        const minDistance = 5;
        const maxDistance = 70;
        const distance = Math.max(minDistance, Math.min(baseDistance, maxDistance));
  
        const cameraHeight = 30;
  
        const direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        const newCameraPosition = center.clone().add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance));
  
        newCameraPosition.y = center.y + cameraHeight;
  
        camera.position.copy(newCameraPosition);
        camera.lookAt(center);
    }
};

I implemented code to center a 3D object on the screen when double right-clicking on it. I expected the object to be centered in the view, regardless of where I am. However, when I was far from the object, the camera either did not center the object properly or placed it out of view. This issue may be related to the fact that the 3D object does not occupy the entire screen, as I have a left sidebar, and I’m not sure if that affects the result.
